# Insert into MySQL database via PHP only half working

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm currently learning PHP, and I'm creating a simple PHP page with a signup form using the POST method. On form submit, the page hashes the password (with phpass), verifies the username is valid (that is, it doesn't exist currently in the db) and inserts if that's true. My code is inserting new rows, but I'm not seeing values for username or hash values being stored. Here's the PHP:

```
require("PasswordHash.php");
$unSuccess = false;
$pwSuccess = false;
$registerSuccess = false; 
$spamSuccess = false;

$database = "XXXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXX";
$server = "XXXXXXX";
$db = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

$user = "";
$pass = "";


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }        


if($_POST["usr"] && !$unSuccess){
    $un = $_POST["usr"];

    if(strlen($un) < 20){
        //Verify Username is valid
        if(preg_match("/([A-Za-z0-9])/", $un) == 1){ 
            //Username is valid, check if it already exists in db. 
            $unCheckQuery = "SELECT USERS.Username FROM USERS WHERE USERS.Username = '$un'"; 
            $result = $db->query($unCheckQuery);
            $num = $result->num_rows;
            $result->close();
            if($num != 0){ $errUsername = "Username already exists."; $unSuccess = false; }
        } 
        else{ 
            //Username is valid and not taken 
            $user = $un; 
            $unSuccess = true; 
        }
    }
}


if($_POST["password"] && !$pwSuccess){
    //verify and hash pw
    $pw = $_POST["password"];
    if(str_len($pw) > 72){die("Password must be shorter than 72 characters");}
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
    $hash = $hasher->HashPassword($pw);
    if(strlen($hash) >= 20 && preg_match($pattern, $pw) == 1){
        $pass = $hash;
        echo $pass;
        $pwSuccess = true;
    }
    else{
        $pwSuccess = false;
    }
}
if($_POST["spam"]){
    $s = $_POST["spam"];
    if($s != 10){
        $spamSuccess = false;
    }
    else if($s == 10) {$spamSuccess = true;}
}

if($unSuccess = true && $pwSuccess = true && $spamSuccess = true){
    $registerQuery = "INSERT INTO USERS(Username, phash) VALUES('$user', '$pass')";
    //This line is breaking evrything.
    $db->query($registerQuery);

}
```

The form I'm using is a simple HTML form. I have omitted login information for obvious reasons. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$unSuccess = true` is assigning, not comparing.

Comment: You might want to double-check your username "validation" logic.  Both your `if` and `else` clauses say `//Username is valid`, so you could be confusing yourself as to what's actually going on there. Also, are you seeing the hashed password displayed in your output as a result of `echo $pass;`?

Comment: What is `str_len`? What is `$pattern`? Have you checked values of `$user`, `$pass` right before quering? They're definitely empty.

Comment: It's not str_len! It's strlen($pw)

Comment: I made a super simple test page for `PasswordHash.php`
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <?php 
             require(PasswordHash.php);
             $password = "Test";
             $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
             $hash = $hasher->HashPassword($password);
            ?>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>$hash</p>
    </body>
</html>`

All the files are in the same directory and its not working.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($unSuccess = true && $pwSuccess = true && $spamSuccess = true)
```

needs to be

```
if($unSuccess == true && $pwSuccess == true && $spamSuccess == true)
```

Comment: It is true of course, but it doesn't cause any errors.

Comment: You can always ditch the `== true` part if your values are *true enough*.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this particular issue was being caused by a security issue on the server end. This code is syntactically correct.